# How to get the host ip dynamically in a docker-compose file?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

For a docker development environment we are using a docker-compose-file. Everything works fine and we are really happy, but there is one tiny issue i would to get working:

We install php-fpm with xdebug. Now we configure it as follows:

*PHP-Dockerfile:*

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-install json \
&& pecl install xdebug \
&& echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

*docker-compose.yml:*

```
services:
  //[...]
  php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    container_name: dev-php
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.0.50
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker"
```

This setup works fine: we are able to debug with xdebug in the IDE on the local system. The only problem is, that we save one IP "192.168.0.50" static in the docker-compose-file. So each employee hast to change it to his own IP before running...

**Now the question:**
is there a smarter way to get the hosts IP-address dynamically when building?

Comment: Rather unrelated question: why do you need to expose `9000` port? Are you trying to connect to php-fpm from outside? What does it offer?

Comment: See this article http://tarunlalwani.com/post/debugging-php-xdebug-docker/

Comment: I'm using phpstorm and i need this port for xdebug.

Comment: And thanks for you link, Tarun. I will keep it in mind for the future. Currently, your soltion with the ssh-tunnel is a bit too complicated for me, since i wanted to keep things simple... ;)

Comment: *"I'm using phpstorm and i need this port for xdebug"* But ... 1) it's xdebug that connects to IDE (outgoing connection) and not other way around ... therefore you do not need to expose xdebug port... 2) You said you are using php-fpm ... and by default it's using TCP 9000 port as well ... so if anything ... you will be exposing php-fpm and not xdebug...

Comment: yep, you are right, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Damn, millions of containers running, yet it is so hard to get the IP of machine which it is running, seriously that's insane, I am searching for viable solution and tried almost everything, ours is multi-node environment, we cannot hardcode IP, it is getting more and more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "magic command" that will get host IP address, so the only way to get around this problem is solution with Environment Variables:

```
services:
  //[...]
   php:
     build: ./docker/php/
     container_name: dev-php
   expose:
     - 9000
   volumes:
     - .:/var/www/html
   environment:
     XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${WORKER_IP}
     PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker"
```

And then pass this variable by .env file:

```
https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/
```

More you can read in documentation:

```
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#configuring-compose-using-environment-variables.
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi Krzysztof and thanks for your reply. Unfortunately docker-compose does not provide the "-e"-attribute for docker-compose up (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).
At the moment, the only working possibilty for me is to use an env-file, which every employee hast to setup by her/his own

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for that. Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

**host.docker.internal**

"From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac [or Docker Desktop for Windows]"

[docker-for-mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/)

[docker-for-windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/)